# Substitution in 2 variable limits

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, substitution

Goodmoring, I'm having difficulty in resolving 2 variable limits with some variable substitution. I can't understand when the substitution is legit or not.
My calculus teacher told me that I've to substitute **x** and **y** with an **invertible function** in order to not excluding some paths.

For example, i was trying to solve $\lim_{(x,y)->(0,0)} \frac{x^2-2y^2}{x-3y}$.
In the first place i tried $y=-\frac{t}{3}$, which is invertible, so the limit becomes
$\lim_{(x,t)->(0,0)} \frac{x^2-\frac{2}{9}t^2}{x+t}$.

The limit should not exist(it can be verified taking 2 different curve) but if i try the following substitution(with all invertible functions):

1. For $x>0,t>0$:
   $a=\sqrt{x}, b=\sqrt{t}$
2. For $x<0,t>0$:
   $a=-\sqrt{-x}, b=\sqrt{t}$
3. For $x<0,t<0$:
   $a=-\sqrt{-x}, b=-\sqrt{-t}$
4. For $x>0,t<0$:
   $a=\sqrt{x}, b=-\sqrt{-t}$

The limit in all the cases about becomes
$\lim_{(a,b)->(0,0)} \frac{a^4-2b^4}{a^2+b^2}$.

If i substitute $a=\rho cos(\theta), b=\rho sin(\theta)$ the limit becomes:
$\lim_{\rho->0} \rho^2(cos^4(\theta)-sin^4(teta))=0$.

So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong(It's my calculus teacher who suggested to split the problem and to do 4 substitution. Is it wrong?)

Comment: I don't quite see the point in substituting $y=-\frac t3$. Try instead $y=kx$ for some $k\in\Bbb R$. The remaining limit has a value that depends on $k$, so the original limit does not exist.

Comment: I would consider the path $$y=\frac{x-\sin^3(x)}{3}$$

Comment: @user170231 Thanks for the answer. I know that the limit doesn't exist if I consider different paths. My problem is that i don't understand what's wrong with my substitution(which leads to 0). I haven't quite understood when I can substitute and when I'm considering only some restriction.

Comment: Making those replacements sooner, with $x=\rho\cos(\theta)$ and $y=\rho\sin(\theta)$, you would have$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2-2y^2}{x-3y}=\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{\rho(\cos^2(\theta)-2\sin^2(\theta))}{\cos(\theta)-3\sin(\theta)}$$but this is zero only if $\cos(\theta)\neq3\sin(\theta)$. The error lies in the change from $(x,t)$ to $(a,b)$.

Comment: Oh thanks, but isn't "cos(θ)≠3sin(θ)" from the domain of the function? Or I can get really close so that doesn't count? In particular I would be very grateful if you could tell me what is wrong with the substitution to (a,b). In a lesson I think my teacher said that it was legit. Thanks.

Comment: In the cases with $x<0$ and/or $t<0$, you would have them replaced with $x=-a^2$ and $t=-b^2$ in the denominator, and upon converting to polar coordinates the denominator does not reduce to just $\rho^2$. For instance, your case 2 leads to$$\lim_{(a,b)\to(0,0)}\frac{a^4-2b^4}{\color{red}{-a^2}+b^2}=\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{\rho^2\left(\cos^4(\theta)-\frac29\sin^4(\theta)\right)}{-\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)}$$but the limit does not exist if $\theta=$ odd multiple of $\frac\pi4$.

Comment: @user170231 Oh you're right, I really missed that. Thanks. So the substitution is correct? Can i split the problem in 4 cases?

Comment: @user170231 And can I be sure that the limit you quoted doesn't exist? Because if pi->odd multiple of pi/4, the denominator->0, but if rho->0 also the numerator->0, so I have and indeterminate form right?

Comment: Aside from the sign management, what you've done is fine, if a bit overkill IMO. The limit exists and is $0$ only for cases 1 and 3, and doesn't exist otherwise. I don't think "indeterminate form" is the right terminology, however. When $\theta=\frac\pi4$, $\frac{\cos^4(\theta)-\sin^4(\theta)}{-\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)}$ is just undefined.